# PHP SQL Case when value like

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use case when to count the total when the column 'Name' has the value 'apple' in it.

So for example, I have 3 values in my column 'Name'.

hallo (apple), hallo today, hallo (apple)

I am trying to count the result which contains apple and I do not want it in the where part of the statement.

I am trying to accomplish this with the following statement, but I get a SQL error around the like operator. Is what I want possible and if so how do I do it?

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = LIKE '%(apple)%' THEN 1 ELSE null end) AS TotalApples
FROM account WHERE id IN (0,$in)
```

I expect the result of this query to be 2 as the (apple) is 2 times present in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the LIKE operator, you do not need the = operator

Hence, for your case please change

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = LIKE '%(apple)%' THEN 1 ELSE null end) AS TotalApples
FROM account WHERE id IN (0,$in)
```

to

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%(apple)%' THEN 1 ELSE null end) AS TotalApples
FROM account WHERE id IN (0,$in)
```

Note: The clause `WHERE id IN (0,$in)` will only retrieve data where id is 0 or equal to $in. If this is not the case you want then please amend this where clause

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need it to search the value (apple). The value itself in my production case is between brackets. so it is litterly (apple) I need counted. I what is in the like operator doing that? I assumed it did when searching for the pattern. Or are the brackets adding making sure this is not correct?

Comment: I just slightly amended my answer after knowing that you need to search for (apple) instead of apple . Please note that it is the = operator which conflicts with LIKE causing the problem, as stated in the first line of my answer

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. Should have figured that out myself.. Sorry for the bother !